# query and while loop don't work correctly when query returns zero rows

Tags: php, mysql

My query and while loop that parses the rows works correctly when the number of rows > 0, but not when =0.

When the number of rows returned is 0, it seems the entire while loop is skipped. See the comment where `$activeCount` is forced =0 and the following error message does not execute and appear.

Before the code below, a default error message is set in the array $errorMessages[], and it is updated and added to when triggers occur. The update for $error_NoActives does not occur when 0 rows return in the query.

Here's relevant code.

```
//fetch the user's active posts and their count
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (
    SELECT propertyID, streetAddress, city3, city2 FROM residence.property
    INNER JOIN contact ON residence.contact.ContactID = residence.property.ContactID
    WHERE residence.contact.contactEmailAddress1 ='$contactEmailAddress1' AND activePosting = '1') props,
    (SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS 'activeCount') actives;")
    or die('<li class=error>Ooops</li>'. mysql_error());

//create HTML li items to show each posting and create jQuery to insert to a div
$rowCount = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    $activeCount = $row["activeCount"];
    //$activeCount = 0; //test - get default error message, seems next 3+ lines are not executing when query has 0 rows
    if( $activeCount == 0 ) {
    $error_NoActives = "<li>You have $activeCount active postings.</li>";
    //don't get this message with 0 active posts, get default error
    $errorMessages[0] = $error_NoActives;
    } else {
        //$activeCount displays correctly if non-zero
        $error_NumberOfActives = "<ul>Welcome back. You have $activeCount active postings.
        //do stuff using $rowCount. Construct li items.
        $rowCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect I don't understand something about while loops, or about MySQL's FOUND_ROWS() and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

Whatever, the $error_NoActives statement is not executing when the query returns 0 rows.

Comment: You are missing a double quotation at the end of your code...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the `mysql_xxx()` in PHP are deprecated and not recommended for use. If at all possible, you should be switching your code to use the PDO library instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop will only run if there are results. That's functioning correctly, because if it tried to run with no results then all the values in $row would be null.

The correct way to do what you want is to use mysql_num_rows thusly:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($fetch)) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
        $error_NumberOfActives = "<ul>Welcome back. You have $activeCount active postings.
        //Do stuff with $row.
    }
} else {
    $error_NoActives = "<li>You have $activeCount active postings.</li>";
}
```

You can completely remove the SELECT FOUND_ROWS() from your query.

Also, another point of note is your die statement. If you're just using that while testing then it's OK. But don't rely on die statements for live code. A better solution is:

```
$query = "mysqlquery";
if(mysql_query($query)) {
} else {
    //some error code
}
```

That was you can handle the error better.

Comment: Styphon, it works - sweet. I also learned something about the while loop that is not in my book. I appreciate your tips about the 2 other points.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop is not run, because there is nothing to loop through because you have 0 rows. Set a if statement around the WHILE if there are more than 0 rows and in the else you can have your code if there are 0 rows. Also fixed a syntax error at your welcome message.

```
//fetch the user's active posts and their count
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (
    SELECT propertyID, streetAddress, city3, city2 FROM residence.property
    INNER JOIN contact ON residence.contact.ContactID = residence.property.ContactID
    WHERE residence.contact.contactEmailAddress1 ='$contactEmailAddress1' AND activePosting = '1') props,
    (SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS 'activeCount') actives;")
    or die('<li class=error>Ooops</li>'. mysql_error());
//create HTML li items to show each posting and create jQuery to insert to a div
$rowCount = 0;
if( mysql_num_rows($fetch) > 0 )
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        $activeCount = $row["activeCount"];
        //$activeCount = 0; //test - get default error message, seems next 3+ lines are not executing when query has 0 rows

            //$activeCount displays correctly if non-zero
            $error_NumberOfActives = "<ul>Welcome back. You have $activeCount active postings.";
            //do stuff using $rowCount. Construct li items.
            $rowCount++;
            }
    }
}
else {
    $error_NoActives = "<li>You have $activeCount active postings.</li>";
    //don't get this message with 0 active posts, get default error
    $errorMessages[0] = $error_NoActives;
}
```

Comment: Niels, thanks. Your code would work also, but Styphon posted first.

Comment: Please look at the time posted, but no worries =)

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Maybe they were displayed in reverse order.